# Compare two array of objects and get only the different Property of the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
Array1 = { "Name": "Max", "Occupation": "Agri", "Location": "KGP" }; 

Array2 = { "Name": "Alex", "Occupation": "S.E", "Location": "KGP" };
```

In the above given 2 arrays i have different values in properties Name and Occupation but the location have the same value as that of Array1,

i want to compare the two arrays and get only the Different Property(Name and Occupation) of Array1

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: `name` and `occupation` are the properties. You're looking for the different values of those properties.

Comment: i see only objects.

Comment: yes we have compare the two arrays and we have to get the properties of different values (i,e) name and occupation are different so we have to get only the property values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over the keys of `object1` and check the difference with the properties of `object2`. If unequal, assign the value to the property of the result `object3`.

```js
var object1 = { "Name": "Max", "Occupation": "Agri", "Location": "KGP" },
    object2 = { "Name": "Alex", "Occupation": "S.E", "Location": "KGP" },
    object3 = {};

Object.keys(object1).forEach(function (k) {
    if (object1[k] !== object2[k]) {
        object3[k] = object1[k];
    }
});

console.log(object3);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj1 = { "Name": "Max", "Occupation": "Agri", "Location": "KGP" }; 

var obj2 = { "Name": "Alex", "Occupation": "S.E", "Location": "KGP" }; 

function getDifference(obj1,obj2){
  var diff = [];
  Object.keys(obj1).forEach(function(key){
  if (obj1[key] !== obj2[key]) diff.push(key);
  });
  return diff;
}
console.log(getDifference(obj1,obj2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Array1 and Array2 are [JavaScript Object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp). With 2 objects, you can perform this working, but dirty comparison. As soon as you will have more properties ... This will be a mess.

```
   var result = {};

    if (Array1.Name !== Array2.Name)
       result.Name = Array1.Name;
    if (Array1.Occupation !== Array2.Occupation)
       result.Occupation = Array1.Occupation.

   return result;
```

Arrays in JavaScript are declared with the following syntax:

```
var Array1 = [];
```

If you want an array of objects, you can write:

```
var Array1 = [ { "Name": "Max", "Occupation": "Agri", "Location": "KGP" }, { b"Name": "Max", "Occupation": "Agri", "Location": "KGP"} ]
```

But I doubt this is your intention there.

Comment: Feel free to correct yourself so, but notice that both Nina Scholz and Vladu Ionut's answers are more adaptative: they will work whatever properties you have, not only with `Name` and `Occupation`. I would recommend you taking one of their code.

Answer (score 0):

If the objective is to get mismatching keys, you can try something like this:

```js
function getMismatchKeys(o1,o2){
  return Object.keys(o1).filter(function(k){
    return o1.hasOwnProperty(k) && o2.hasOwnProperty(k) && o1[k] !== o2[k]
  });
}

var obj1 = { "Name": "Max", "Occupation": "Agri", "Location": "KGP" }; 
var obj2 = { "Name": "Alex", "Occupation": "S.E", "Location": "KGP" }; 

console.log(getMismatchKeys(obj1, obj2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that Array1 and Array2 are meant to be json objects and not json arrays. I will also assume that you want a resulting object that is made up of only the key value pairs of Array1 which differ from Array2. Given those assumption you could use [lodash omitBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.1#omitBy) to solve your problem.

```js
var Array1 = { "Name": "Max", "Occupation": "Agri", "Location": "KGP" };
var Array2 = { "Name": "Alex", "Occupation": "S.E", "Location": "KGP" };
var result = _.omitBy(Array1, function(val, key){ return val === Array2[key];});
console.log('the key value pairs of Array1 that are different from Array2 are: ', result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```